# Shiny, how to call the filter functionality from datatable?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Suppose that I have the following code where I want to make the radioButtons filter a data.table on the 'vs' column= 0 or 1, is this possible?

I am looking to filter the renderDataTable (not mtcars) so that you can keep on using '_rows_selected' capabilities etc.

```
library(DT)

ui <- basicPage(
  h2("The mtcars data"),
  radioButtons("vs_radio", label="filter on vs",
               c("0" = "0",
                 "1" = "1"), inline = TRUE),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    mtcars
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are interested in getting the original row index of the `mtcars` dataset, you can add an additional column to the `mtcars` with the row index. Later you can filter that new dataset using the radio button inside a reactive expression. You can use the `options` on the `renderDataTable` to hide the additional column. Finally, you can use the `_rows_selected` to retrieve the original row index by reading the additional column (`row`) of the reactive dataset. Maybe there is a better solution, but the code below could be useful.

```R
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- basicPage(
  h2("The mtcars data"),
  radioButtons("vs_radio", label="filter on vs",
               c("0" = "0",
                 "1" = "1"), inline = TRUE),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable"),
  h4("Selected rows:"),
  verbatimTextOutput("selectedRows")
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # add an additional column with the row index of the original dataset
  dat <- mtcars
  dat$row <- 1:nrow(dat)

  # react to the radio button to filter dataset
  filteredDat <- reactive({
    vs <- as.numeric(input$vs_radio)
    dat[dat$vs == vs, ]
  })

  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    filteredDat()},
    options = list(
        # hide column "row"
        columnDefs = list(list(targets = 12, visible = FALSE))
      )
  )
  
  output$selectedRows <- renderPrint({ 
    idx <- input$mytable_rows_selected
    filteredDat()[idx, "row"]
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I am actually looking for a way to call the filters from datatable directly, because now if you use the filter it forgets the row selection. Of course, there would be a solution to also remember the row selection, but it quickly gets very complicated if you have complicated filters/actions. So I prefer to somehow call the filter functionality from datatable (the one that you can put on top or bottom) and was wondering if that is possible?